# MySQL: which innodb parameters should I tune if disk I/O is slow

Tags: mysql

Which InnoDB parameters should I tune if disk I/O is slow?

Please give your suggestions.

I have another question regarding innodb_log_file :- 
What happen if innodb_log_file become full ? so what is mysql next action on this situation ?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and short on specifics! What do you mean by slow? What is your hardware (CPU, RAM, HDD/SSD) and what queries are you running? How much data is in the relevant tables? What are the timings of problematic queries (give the query as formatted text as well as the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G`

Comment: If the disk is busy due to a slow query, let's work on the query!  It may be as simple as adding a composite index.  There is a lot more _potential_ gain this way than by tweaking hardware.

Comment: Please update your question by telling us the results of SELECT @@VERSION; Also, how much RAM, Cores available and do you have magnetic, SSD or NVME data storage?

Comment: @udayrajgupta   Please put your SECOND question on the system as a new question.  Someone will answer you.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on why your disk I/O is slow and how many safeties you are willing to disable. Some examples:

`sync_binlog=0` # if you use binlogs - you could lose up to typically 5 seconds of transactions that were written to the binlog

`innodb_doublewrite=0` # you will end up with corrupted data if a page written to the transaction log is torn due to a crash or power failure

`innodb_flush_logs_at_trx_commit=0` # you will lose up to typically 5 seconds of transactions that were written to InnoDB.

`innodb_io_capacity` and `innodb_io_capacity_max` - make sure these are set appropriately for your disk speed. Defaults are 200 and 2000 respectively, which is probably too high for regular SATA HDDs and certainly too low for SSDs, especially high end NVMe SSDs.